# Why do I get the error `'class std::shared_ptr<Tree>' has no member named 'string' std::cout << *it->string`?

Tags: c++

Why do I get this error?

```
'class std::shared_ptr<Tree>' has no member named 'string'
std::cout << *it->string
```

If I replace the iteration with this:

```cpp
for(auto it : t.children){}
```

Everything works perfectly fine.

Why does it not work here?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

class Tree{
public:
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Tree> > children;
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> string;

    Tree(std::shared_ptr<std::string> s){
        this->string = s;
    }

    ~Tree(){}
};

int main(){
    Tree t = Tree( std::make_shared<std::string>("hello") );        
    std::cout << "t.string\t" << *t.string << std::endl;
    t.children.push_back(std::make_shared<Tree>( std::make_shared<std::string>("world") ));

    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Tree> >::iterator it;
    for (it = t.children.begin(); it < t.children.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << *it->string << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `(*it)->string`

Comment: @0x499602D2 Worked, thanks.